# Where I can file the layout file <update handle="empty"/> in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts

In `/magento2/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/1column.xml` I see this tag update handle="empty"

Can you please explain what this mean? I thought it's an "include" tag but where is this **empty.xml** file?

Comment: see here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the base page layout of the theme module:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/page_layout

In Magento 2 the frontend and backend can share layout code if it's placed in the `view/base` directory.

Answer (score 2):

you can find **empty.xml** file from below location,

```
magento2/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/page_layout/
```

Its used in all layout of 1column.xml format.